# How to format calculated column number in Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, flow, power-automate

I am using a calculated column (number) in a SharePoint list, and putting the value into an email using a Power Automate Flow. The value will always be an integer.

When the value is passed through to Flow, it's converted to a string with a decimal point and 14 zero's added, so 7 becomes 7.00000000000000.

How can I format this to be an integer with no trailing decimal in Flow?

Comment: How many decimal places you have set to your calculated column from settings?

Comment: @GaneshSanap It's set to no decimal places.

Comment: Ok, Try my solution given below. let me know if it works for you or if you come across any issue.

Comment: I have the same problem, after applying this method and I am getting an error. > "InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in
> action 'Send_an_email_(V2)' inputs at line '1' and column '14597':
> 'The template language function 'int' was invoked with a parameter
> that is not valid. The value cannot be converted to the target
> type.'." Do you have an idea what can be the reason? P.S. In SharePoint, I selected Number for data output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below formula:

```
formatNumber(int(outputs('<Get SharePoint Data Action Name>')?['body/<calculated column name>']), '0,0.00', 'en-us')
```

This will convert your calculated column to `#,#.00` format (with 2 decimal points).

If you want the number without decimal points then you can use below formula:

```
formatNumber(int(outputs('<Get SharePoint Data Action Name>')?['body/<calculated column name>']), '0,0', 'en-us')
```

Replace `Get SharePoint Data Action Name` and `calculated column name` with your action name and calculate column name respectively.

You can convert the string to number in Microsoft flow using [int](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#int) function.

And You can format the number to desired format in Microsoft flow using [formatNumber](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#formatNumber) function.

**Flow**:

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm struggling to pass through the column value to the function. I'm using the 'When an item or file is modified' trigger, which can return an array of items (it will only ever return one in my case). Would you mind taking a look if I add a screenshot to my question?

Comment: Sure, what is the name of your calculated column? Also, where are you using calculated column value? I am not able to see email body (if you are showing number value in body) in screenshot attached.

Comment: The column name is 'SLA', thanks for your help!

Comment: Also, why are you using "Apply to each" action when you are getting only one item?

Comment: Flow inserted it automatically, the only trigger I can find that only fires on file modification is 'When an item or file is modified', which I guess can return multiple items.

Comment: I managed to use a the 'When an item is created or modified' trigger, and add a condition to only proceed when the item is modified. Your answer was perfect for the original question, so I've edited back to that. Thanks again!

Comment: Great, I am glad it worked for you.